# Unusual behavior in evaluating the expressions in C

Tags: c

I am executing this code, but i am not able to get why the 6th part is showing answer 2 instead of 1.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x[3][5] = {
                    {1,2,3,4,5},
                    {6,7,8,9,10},
                    {11,12,13,14,15}
                    };
    int *n =  (int *)&x;

    printf("1) %d\n2) %d\n3) %d\n4) %d\n5) %d", *(*(x+2)+1), *(*x + 2)+5, *(*(x+1)), *(*x +2)+1, *(*(x+1) +3) );
    printf("\n6) %d\n7) %d\n8) %d\n9) %d\n10) %d\n", *(n+0), *(n+2), (*(n+3) + 1), *(n+5) +1, ++*n);                
}
```

Output of the code is :

```
1) 12
2) 8
3) 6
4) 4
5) 9
6) 2 // i am not getting this.
7) 3
8) 5
9) 7
10) 2
```

According to me the answer of part 6th must be 1. Why this is so?

Comment: The order in which function parameters is evaluated is not specified, so using the pre-increment operator `++*n` is just asking for trouble.

Comment: What is the reason for this unusual behavior? According to other answers it is evaluating from left to right. @user3386109

Comment: Then the other answers must be talking about the behavior of a specific compiler. The C standard says the arguments can be evaluated in any order.

Comment: But i have learnt that they can evaluate either from left to right or from right to left. @user3386109

Comment: @harshitbatra: That's incorrect.  It is not guaranteed to make any sense at all, if you ignore rules about sequence points.  So it's possible that it won't make sense no matter what order you put it in.  The only way to get predictable results is to fix the errors in your code.

Comment: so i must right separate expressions (or individual printf) for each of them, to get predictable results. Is it so? @DietrichEpp

Comment: You just need to separate out expressions like `++*n` from `*(n+0)`, which is equivalent to `*n`.  You can't use `++*n` and `*n` in the same expression.

Comment: This kind of thing can surprise people, it's a little less surprising if you know how optimizing compilers work.